# Is it a good practice to return constant values as views columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have device type string constants used in our stored procedures like this

```
select * from Device.BvDetails where deviceType='bv'
select * from Device.UcbDetails where deviceType='ucb'
```

I wanted to remove this hard coding from everywhere, but I have limitation that I cannot have a device type static database table, so I came up with the solution to have a view like this

```
CREATE VIEW Machine.DeviceType
AS
SELECT 
       'bv'  AS Bv,
       'ucb' AS Ucb
```

And use it like this

```
Declare @bvDeviceType varchar(10) = (select Bv from Machine.DeviceType)    
select * from Device.BvDetails where deviceType=@bvDeviceType

Declare @ucbDeviceType varchar(10) = (select Ucb from Machine.DeviceType)    
select * from Device.UcbDetails where deviceType=@ucbDeviceType
```

Is the way correct in the sense of best practices and performance?

Comment: Why do you think the string constants are bad?  If they are meaningful to the users of the DB then they seem like a natural approach -- although you might want constraints of some sort to validate that the names are valid.

Comment: A `VIEW` that only has string literal seems pretty pointless, I must say.

Comment: Also you mention stored procedures in your opening sentance, but those statements are against tables/views; you can't `SELECT` from a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Larnu - I meant I have statements like the ones I put there inside stored procedures. I just gave example of some statements that use device type hardcoding

Comment: @GordonLinoff - They are good if they are used just once. But what if they are used in multiple stored procedures and one day if the device type name is changed?

Comment: @PawanNogariya . . . Then you should have a reference table, not a view, and enforce the values using foreign key constraints.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have mentioned in the question that I have a limitation that I cannot have a reference table, otherwise yes that is the ideal solution.

Comment: You can make the view with two (or more) columns and one row for each device type and use it to do a lookup, but at some point you need something stable, i.e. a `DeviceTypeId`, `DeviceTypeCode`, `DeviceTypeName`, that you will look up. Otherwise you're just pushing the problem to another level. It's a little silly when `@bvDeviceType` is set to `'ucb'` because the types have changed. Extending the view still lacks the benefits of foreign key constraints.